# LLVM mark function as const and remove duplicate calls

Tags: llvm

I have an external (C) function that I am calling in my LLVM IR.  The IR gets JITed and everything works fine, but the generated code is performance sensitive, and I want to remove duplicate calls to my external function if possible.  The function has no side effects.  Is there a FunctionPass that eliminates redundant calls to the function?  Is there something I have to do to mark the function as having no side effects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#function-attributes you can specify the attributes readonly or readnone for a function:

```
declare i32 @fn(i32 %i);
declare i32 @readonly_fn(i32 %i) readonly;
declare i32 @readnone_fn(i32 %i) readnone;
```

`readonly` means that the function doesn't write memory,
`readnone` means that it doesn't even read memory (for example sin() could be readnone)

If a function doesn't write memory, it should return the result only based on the parameters, and therefor be a pure function (if the global state doesn't change). In case of a readnone function, even the global state could change.

The llvm optimizer can optimize calls to readonly and readnone functions with the `EarlyCSE` pass (common subexpression elimination), as shown in the following example:

using the following test functions

```
define i32 @test_no_readonly()
{
  %1 = call i32 @fn(i32 0)
  %2 = call i32 @fn(i32 0)
  %add = add i32 %1, %2
  ret i32 %add
}
define i32 @test_readonly()
{
  %1 = call i32 @readonly_fn(i32 0)
  %2 = call i32 @readonly_fn(i32 0)
  %add = add i32 %1, %2
  ret i32 %add
}
define i32 @test_readnone()
{
  %1 = call i32 @readnone_fn(i32 0)
  %2 = call i32 @readnone_fn(i32 0)
  %add = add i32 %1, %2
  ret i32 %add
}
```

and running `opt -early-cse -S readonly_fn.ll > readonly_fn_opt.ll` optimizes away the second call for the readonly and readnone functions, resulting in

```
define i32 @test_no_readonly() {
  %1 = call i32 @fn(i32 0)
  %2 = call i32 @fn(i32 0)
  %add = add i32 %1, %2
  ret i32 %add
}

define i32 @test_readonly() {
  %1 = call i32 @readonly_fn(i32 0)
  %add = add i32 %1, %1
  ret i32 %add
}

define i32 @test_readnone() {
  %1 = call i32 @readnone_fn(i32 0)
  %add = add i32 %1, %1
  ret i32 %add
}
```

The `readonly_fn` and `readnone_fn` functions are only called once, thus eleminating redundand calls.

The `-functionattrs` pass can also add these attributes to defined functions